# EL works but JSTL does not, using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I've been on this for hours and still can't figure it out! Searched through all the related topics on JSTL but no luck.

My site is using Spring 3.1, JSTL used to work, but after I've switched to a new comp and re-setup the environment, it doesn't. I don't know what's missing!

What's interesting is that when I do a simple `<c:out value="${topWorks}"/>` it returns error "Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /user/indexx.jsp (line: 176, column: 5) No tag "out" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c""

But my EL is working because all the javascript and css are loaded, because I use

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here's what I have:

1. On top of JSP page`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`
2. web.xml is 3.0

   ```
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
   ```
3. Servlet has jstlview

   ```
   <bean id="jstlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
   <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
   <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   ```

4.POM file, included jstl libs (i've also tried dropping the jstl-1.2 as suggested by stackExchange's JSTL info page, doesn't work either)

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
  <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1-b04</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api-osgi</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>webservices-api-osgi</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-SP3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
    <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ognl</groupId>
  <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<!-- For image process -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
  <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
  <version>[0.4, 0.5)</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for Thumbnailator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
    <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.8</version>
</dependency>


<!-- for multi file upload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

here's the complete error message

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /user/indexx.jsp (line: 176, column: 5) No tag "out" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.yuting.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

JSP page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>XXX</title>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <!-- news ticker -->
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap-->
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/Bootstrap/SlateBootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/appleColorsBootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
              <c:out value="${topWorks}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Spring servlet config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">   
    <description>Spring-DispatcherServlet</description>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yuting"/>

    <bean id="jstlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">  
        <property name="order" value="2" />  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName">
            <value>cim_locale</value>
        </property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge">
            <value>31536000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" cache-period="31556926"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <dwr:configuration />   
       <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />
       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
         <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
         <property name="mappings">
         <props>
           <prop key="/dwr/**/*">dwrController</prop>
         </props>
         </property>
       </bean>  
    <dwr:annotation-scan base-package="com.yuting.*" scanDataTransferObject="true" scanRemoteProxy="true"/>   


</beans>
```

Comment: You have JSTL and taglibs in the 'compile' scope.

Comment: @Dave Thanks. but what should it be? I've changed to runtime doesn't work, remove it is same as compile... doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around for a while, I've managed to solve it, still used the method our site suggested. But I've found that I had an extra folder called tag with some custom tags in it, deleted those, and removed all the jstl related libraries in POM. And it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your taglib is wrong, try this in your jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Comment: I have this already '<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>', for some reason it doesn't show up in my original post in #1, the code is messing it up

Comment: I guess you have two problems, 1) Maybe your jsp file is wrong and 2) There is a bad configuration in your servlet jstlview resolver, there is no the "WEB-INF/view" path where you put all jsp files.

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate more? 2. Yes, I don't have web-inf/view but I don't see how this is related... Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Show me both, indexx jsp file and the servlet configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, fall asleep.... Just updated on top added jsp and servlet config, please help! thank you